# Apparently \IfFileExists not working with otf?

Tags: luatex, kpathsea

Using TeXlive 2023, Linux, lualatex.

To my surprise, `\IfFileExists` does not seem to find any `*.otf` file, regardless of whether the file is installed into `texmf-dist` or my `texmf` home directory. MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\IfFileExists{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}{
  \typeout{FOUND IT}
}{
  \typeout{NOT FOUND} % This is the response.
}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\begin{document}
Hello World. % Prints in LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf.
\end{document}
```

When compiling with `lualatex`, I expect the command-line output (and log file) to have `FOUND IT`, because the file is definitely there. If it try to use the Libertinus Serif font family as my main font, it works. But `\IfFileExists` does not find the file, with its correct file extension.

I realize that that there is a command `\IfFontExists`, but it may take very long if the font is not there, so I do not wish to do it that way.

Comment: it will find any file type, but only if they are in tex's input path, which fonts are usually not

Comment: check `kpsexpand '$TEXINPUTS'`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see the problem now. I was under the (incorrect) impression that "all of" my TEXMFHOME was searched, including fonts and whatnot. Interestingly, it does find a custom font there, but apparently only because it has a tree name that matches my custom document class there.

Comment: unlikely to be the documentclass, isn't your custom font under TEXMFHOME (which is searched in full) it's just texmf-dist that is restricted to tex area in the texlive default setting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is what puzzled me. My custom font in TEXMFHOME is found (I double-checked to ensure that it is not elsewhere). But if I place an un-installed *otf font (such as LobsterTwo) in TEXMFHOME/fonts/opentype/impallari/lobster2 and update using `luaotfload-tool` (probably unnecessary), then not found. Needs further investigation. Problem may lie elsewhere. Anyway, I can put a copy of the font in same directory as main document, and explicitly call for it using `./fontfilename.otf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\IfFileExists` you can only search the `$TEXINPUTS` tree, that is, files which make sense for `\input` (along with possibly something that has been added by hand).

You can define a function that does lookups in the whole `texmf-dist` tree (almost), using `kpsewhich`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\IfFileInTEXTree}{O{}mmm}
 {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { kpsewhich~#1~#2 } {\escapechar=-1\scan_stop:} \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VTF \l_tmpa_tl { #4 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\IfFileInTEXTree{LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf}{%
  \typeout{FOUND IT}%
}{
  \typeout{NOT FOUND}%
}

\IfFileInTEXTree{whatever.otf}{%
  \typeout{FOUND IT}%
}{
  \typeout{NOT FOUND}%
}

\stop
```

You can also add options to `kpsewhich` (see its manual)

```
\IfFileInTEXTree[<options>]{<filename>}{<true>}{<false>
```

This doesn't require unrestricted shell escape, just the default restricted shell escape.

The log file will show

```
(|kpsewhich  LibertinusSerif-Regular.otf)
FOUND IT
(|kpsewhich  whatever.otf)
NOT FOUND
```

Comment: Very helpful! For a long timel, I have been testing if a font file exists, incorrectly. But it will nevertheless load the font, if there. Did not notice the problem until I put the load command within the test logic. See my modified MWE. Now I know what to do